# Direct vs uniform initialization in std::allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization

> <sub>This question has also been submitted to Usenet, where it is more appropriate, but this is a larger and more reliable forum.</sub>

`std::allocator::construct` is defined to forward its argument parameter
pack to object construction using parentheses, a.k.a. direct-initialization.

If it used braces, a.k.a. uniform initialization, we could initialize
aggregate data types from functions such as `std::make_shared` and
`container::emplace`. Also, it would be acceptable to put the contents
of an initializer list into the argument list of such a function,
solving the problem of `initializer_list` type deduction under
forwarding.

Was this alternative considered and rejected? Is it too late to switch
in a future standard? It seems this would be a breaking change, but
not a particularly heinous one.

Comment: Stack Overflow larger than _Usenet_?! :P

Comment: @Tomalak: Larger than comp.std.c++ and comp.lang.c++.moderated, where I submitted. And much saner than the comp.lang.c++ madhouse, with which I didn't bother.

Comment: How do you gain reputation on Usenet? I've been wondering that for some time...

Comment: @KerrekSB: That sounds antithetical to Usenet. The goal there is to harass people until the real-world police come for you.

Comment: For the record: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8783004/981959 has Potatoswatter's follow up on this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know what the SC considered, but keep in mind that uniform initialization doesn't really 'work' in generic contexts (barring value construction*). Consider this attempt:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T
make(Args&&... args)
{
    return T { std::forward<Args>(args)... };
}
```

You get:

```
assert( make<std::vector<int>>(10, 0).size() == 2 );
assert( std::vector<int>(10, 0).size() == 10 );
```

and this doesn't compile:

```
make<std::vector<int*>>(10u, 0);
```

whereas this does:

```
std::vector<int*>(10u, 0);
```

If the particular interaction between perfect forwarding and initializer lists that causes this was formalized soon enough I could see the SC not wanting to restart from scratch.

(*): `T {}` is fine even in generic contexts.

Comment: Bah, the Do The Right Thing construct. I haven't been bitten by that one yet. Still it would be nice to have an alternative. The Standard requires that `std::is_constructible::value` be `true` for the arguments of `construct`; direct initialization could be a fallback provided by an implementation under the umbrella of UB.

Comment: @Potatoswatt Since that trait would return `true` iff the type is constructible using direct initialization, I think you mean that the fallback be uniform initialization. An interesting idea, that's backward compatible with the current rules.