# C++11 emplace_back on vector<struct>?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following program:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct T
{
    int a;
    double b;
    string c;
};

vector<T> V;

int main()
{
    V.emplace_back(42, 3.14, "foo");
}
```

It doesn't work:

```
$ g++ -std=gnu++11 ./test.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/allocator.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:43,
                 from ./test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = T; _Args = {int, double, const char (&)[4]}; _Tp = T]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/alloc_traits.h:253:4:   required from ‘static typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = T; _Args = {int, double, const char (&)[4]}; _Alloc = std::allocator<T>; typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type = void]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/alloc_traits.h:390:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = T; _Args = {int, double, const char (&)[4]}; _Alloc = std::allocator<T>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/vector.tcc:97:6:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {int, double, const char (&)[4]}; _Tp = T; _Alloc = std::allocator<T>]’
./test.cpp:17:32:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:110:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘T::T(int, double, const char [4])’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:110:4: note: candidates are:
./test.cpp:6:8: note: T::T()
./test.cpp:6:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
./test.cpp:6:8: note: T::T(const T&)
./test.cpp:6:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
./test.cpp:6:8: note: T::T(T&&)
./test.cpp:6:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
```

What is the correct way to do this and why?

(Also tried single and double braces)

Comment: That will work if you provide an appropriate constructor.

Comment: Is there a way to construct it in-place with the automatically created brace struct constructor used by `T t{42,3.14, "foo"}`?

Comment: I don't think that takes the form of a constructor. It's aggregate initialization.

Comment: See [Why doesn't emplace_back() use uniform initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782895/why-doesnt-emplace-back-use-uniform-initialization).

Comment: I am not trying to affect your opinion in any way.. But in case you did not give attention to thin question from a while.. The accepted answer, with full respect to its writer, is not an answer at all to your question and may mislead the readers.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: Fine, I changed it to the answer that points out that this will be "fixed" in C++20.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For anyone from the future, this behavior [will be changed](http://wg21.link/p0960) in [C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

In other words, even though implementation internally will still call `T(arg0, arg1, ...)` it will be considered as regular `T{arg0, arg1, ...}` that you would expect.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question that was asked. Can you clarify?

Comment: @MarkR struct `T` with fields `a`,`b`,`c` and no constructor is constructible as `T{x,y,z}` but not as `T(x,y,z)`.

Comment: I am from the future and can confirm: This does work in GCC and MSVC. Not in Clang, though :( https://compiler-explorer.com/z/qGbGvsqzj

Comment: Sadly, a few years later, this has _not_ changed in C++20 and still malfunctions the same way.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek It *changed* in C++20. Just Clang hasn't implemented this yet. See on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20).

Answer (score 131):

You need to explicitly define a ctor for the class:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct T
{
    int a;
    double b;
    string c;

    T(int a, double b, string &&c) 
        : a(a)
        , b(b)
        , c(std::move(c)) 
    {}
};

vector<T> V;

int main()
{
    V.emplace_back(42, 3.14, "foo");
}
```

The point of using `emplace_back` is to avoid creating a temporary object, which is then copied (or moved) to the destination. While it is also possible to create a temporary object, then pass that to `emplace_back`, it defeats (at least most of) the purpose. What you want to do is pass individual arguments, then let `emplace_back` invoke the ctor with those arguments to create the object in place.

Comment: I think better way would be to write `T(int a, double b, string c) : a(a), b(b), c(std::move(c))`

Comment: The accepted answer defeats the purpose of `emplace_back`. This is the correct answer. This is how `emplace*` work. They construct the element in-place using the forwarded arguments. Hence, a constructor is needed to take said arguments.

Comment: still, vector could provide an emplace_aggr, right?

Comment: @balki Right, there's no point taking `c` by `&&` if nothing is done with its possible rvalueness; at the initialiser of the member, the argument is treated as an lvalue again, in the absence of a cast, so the member just gets copy-constructed. Even if the member was move-constructed, it's not idiomatic to require callers always to pass a temporary or `std::move()`d lvalue (though I will confess that I have a few corner-cases in my code where I do that, but only in implementation details).

Comment: Problem with this is that the struct then no longer is POD

Answer (score 30):

Of course, this is not an answer, but it shows an interesting feature of tuples:

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

using T = tuple <
    int,
    double,
    string
>;

vector<T> V;

int main()
{
    V.emplace_back(42, 3.14, "foo");
}
```

Comment: It certainly isn't an answer. what's so interesting about it? any type with a ctor can be emplaced in this way. tuple has a ctor. the op's struct didn't. _that's_ the answer.

Comment: @underscore_d: I'm not sure that I remember every detail of what I was thinking 3½ years ago, but I thinj what I was suggesting was that if you just use a `tuple` instead of defining a POD struct, then you get a constructor for free, which means that you get the `emplace` syntax for free (among other things -- you also get lexicographic ordering). You lose member names, but sometimes it's less bother creating accessors than all the rest of the boilerplate you would otherwise need. I agree that Jerry Coffin's answer is much better than the accepted one. I also upvoted it years ago.

Comment: Yeah, spelling it out helps me understand what you meant! Good point. I agree that sometimes the generalisation is bearable when weighed against the other stuff the STL provides for us: I use that semi-often with `pair`... but sometimes wonder if I really gain much in net terms, heh. But perhaps `tuple` will follow in the future. Thanks for expanding!

Answer (score 13):

If you do not want to (or cannot) add a constructor, specialize allocator for T (or create your own allocator).

```
namespace std {
    template<>
    struct allocator<T> {
        typedef T value_type;
        value_type* allocate(size_t n) { return static_cast<value_type*>(::operator new(sizeof(value_type) * n)); }
        void deallocate(value_type* p, size_t n) { return ::operator delete(static_cast<void*>(p)); }
        template<class U, class... Args>
        void construct(U* p, Args&&... args) { ::new(static_cast<void*>(p)) U{ std::forward<Args>(args)... }; }
    };
}
```

Note: Member function construct shown above cannot compile with clang 3.1(Sorry, I don't know why).
Try next one if you will use clang 3.1 (or other reasons).

```
void construct(T* p, int a, double b, const string& c) { ::new(static_cast<void*>(p)) T{ a, b, c }; }
```

Comment: In your allocate function, don't you need to worry about alignment?  See `std::aligned_storage`

Comment: No Problem. According to specification, effects of "void* ::operator new(size_t size)" are "The allocation function called by a new-expression to allocate size bytes of storage suitably aligned to represent any object of that size."

Comment: That code is horrifically ugly though. The whole point of the OP is "why doesnt this convenient feature work like I expect it to", nobody other than c++ philosophers wants to write code like this.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be covered in 23.2.1/13.

First, definitions:

> Given a container type X having an allocator_type identical to A and a
>   value_type identical to T and given an lvalue m of type A, a pointer p
>   of type T*, an expression v of type T, and an rvalue rv of type T, the
>   following terms are defined.

Now, what makes it emplace-constructible:

> T is EmplaceConstructible into X from args , for zero or more
>   arguments args, means that the following expression is well-formed:
>   allocator_traits::construct(m, p, args);

And finally a note about the default implementation of the construct call:

> Note: A container calls allocator_traits::construct(m, p, args) to
>   construct an element at p using args. The default construct in
>   std::allocator will call ::new((void*)p) T(args), but specialized
>   allocators may choose a different definition.

This pretty much tells us that for a default (and potentially the only) allocator scheme you *must* have defined a constructor with the proper number of arguments for the thing you're trying to emplace-construct into a container.

Answer (score 7):

emplace_back returns a reference in c++17 and newer, so you can do this...

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct T
{
    int a;
    double b;
    string c;
};

vector<T> V;

int main()
{
    V.emplace_back() = { 42, 3.14, "foo" };
}
```

Comment: Nice. But will it works as "emplace" or just a "push_back" with an rvalue?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ At first glance, it appears that the assignment operator will be invoked...

Answer (score -2):

you have to define a constructor for your type `T` because it contains an `std::string` which is not trivial.

moreover, it would be better to define (possible defaulted) move ctor/assign (because you have a movable `std::string` as member) -- this would help to move your `T` much more efficient...

or, just use `T{...}` to call overloaded `emplace_back()` as recommended in neighboug response... everything depends on your typical use cases...

Comment: A move constructor is automatically generated for T

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: only if no user ctors are defined

Comment: Correct, and they are not.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: but you have to define some, to avoid temporary instance on `emplace_back()` call :)

Comment: Actually incorrect.  A move constructor is automatically generated provided no destructor, copy constructor or assignment operators are defined.  Defining a 3 argument memberwise constructor for use with emplace_back will not supress the default move constructor.

Answer (score -3):

You can create the `struct T` instance and then move it to the vector:

```
V.push_back(std::move(T {42, 3.14, "foo"}));
```

Comment: You don't need to std::move() a temporary object T{...}. It's already a temporary object (rvalue). So you can just drop the std::move() from your example.

Comment: Moreover, even the type name T isn't necessary - the compiler can guess it. So just a "V.push_back{42, 3.14, "foo"}" will work.