# emplacing a POD

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, emplace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++11 emplace_back on vector<struct>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812703/c11-emplace-back-on-vectorstruct)

Is emplacement possible with PODs? It does not seem to work in Visual Studio 2012:

```
struct X
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

void whatever()
{
    std::vector<X> xs;
    X x = {1, 2};

    // okay
    xs.push_back(x);

    // okay
    xs.emplace_back(x);

    //error C2661: 'X::X': error C2661: no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
    xs.emplace_back(1, 2);
}
```

Is this just a shortcoming of Visual Studio 2012, or does emplacing a POD simply not work in C++11?

Comment: It constructs it in place. There's no constructor like that.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it definitive, but g++ (4.7.1) doesn't accept it either.

Comment: I think you probably have to have a constructor for `X` that takes two arguments (as the error message suggests).

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't emplace_back() use uniform initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8782895/636019)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no constructor `X::X(int,int)`, which is what your call to `emplace_back` would use to construct the `X` object. Containers use `allocator_traits<A>::construct(allocator, p, args)` to construct objects, where `p` is a pointer to some allocated space and `args` are the arguments passed to the constructor. This is used by `emplace_back`. This `construct` function calls `::new((void*)p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`, so it doesn't use uniform initialization.

`xs.emplace_back({1, 2})` will also be an error, despite the fact that an aggregate can be constructed with list-initialization. That's because a brace-enclosed initializer list cannot be forwarded.

Comment: Will work fine with a compliant compiler, but not with VC++ 2012 (yet). :-]

Comment: `emplace_back({1, 2})` is an error, `push_back({1, 2})` will work however. List initialization cannot take place in the former as there's nothing to initialize (informally speaking), it's a necessary evil with template argument deduction.