# How to elegantly emplace optional with const values

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17

I am trying to use an `std::optional` to late instantiate an object (which is not valid before). I found an annoying situation, where I do not know how to elegantly solve this.

I have the following data structure:

```
struct Foo {
    int foo1;
    float foo2;
};
```

as a member `std::optional<Foo> foo_`.

In a function

```
void Bar::bar(int const value1, float const value2) {
    foo_.emplace(value1, value2);
}
```

To my surprise, this fails to compile (in GCC 7.1) because it tries to call the constructor of `Foo` with `int const&, float const&`.
Now naive me tried to specialize `emplace` as:

```
foo_.emplace<int, float>(value1, value2);
```

which did not work either because it tries to use `initializer_list` then.

So my question is how does one call emplace elegantly?

Comment: Hint: How would you construct a `Foo` to begin with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add constructor as `emplace` use `()` constructor and not `{}` (which would allow aggregate initialization).

```
struct Foo {
     Foo(int i, float f) : foo1(i), foo2(f) {}

    int foo1;
    float foo2;
};
```

Or be explicit on constructor used:

```
foo_.emplace(Foo{value1, value2});
```

Comment: "be explicit on constructor used" is a bit misleading because your example code would *implicitly* use move constructor  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following wrapper to wrap the aggregate:

```
template< typename type >
struct aggregate_wrapper
    : type
{

    aggregate_wrapper() = default;

    using type::operator =;

    template< typename ...arguments,
              bool is_noexcept = noexcept(::new (std::declval< void * >()) type{std::declval< arguments >()...}) >
    constexpr
    aggregate_wrapper(arguments &&... _arguments) noexcept(is_noexcept)
        : type{std::forward< arguments >(_arguments)...}
    { ; }

};
```

In manner `std::optional< aggregate_wrapper< Foo > >`.

For allocator-aware containers like `std::vector` you can use modification of an allocator like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13845075/1430927) (i.e. with curly braces inside of `construct` instead of parentheses).