# Workaround for not defining constructor for emplace()

Tags: c++, c++11

We have aggregate initialisation since C++11:

```
struct S {
    int count;
    double value;
};
S s{2, 3.0};
```

but in order for this work:

```
vector<S> v;
v.emplace_back(2, 3.0);
```

we need to manually write a constructor for no reason:

```
struct S {
    int count;
    double value;
    S(int count, double value): count(count), value(value) {}
};
```

We also need this constructor for `optional(in_place, ...)` and `variant(in_place_type<>, ...)` to work.

Is there a workaround for not writing this constructor manually?

It doesn't add any information just repeats what's already there, twice. Also the compiler is able to write it itself as it did it for the aggregate initialisation.

I was able to add new constructors to Egg's variant which allowed this but can we do something without modifying the container's source?

Edit: this question: [Why doesn't emplace_back() use uniform initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782895/why-doesnt-emplace-back-use-uniform-initialization) is related but does not offer a workaround.

Comment: `v.emplace_back(S{2, 3.0});` ?

Comment: @kerrytazi That defeats the purpose of using `emplace_back`.  Might as well use `push_back` at that point.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13845075/4342498) looks to have a clever work around

Comment: @SombreroChicken, thanks, I know the reasons, I'm looking for workaround.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, a little heavy-weight but good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one implicit constructor available.

```
std::vector<S> v;
v.emplace_back(S{2, 3.0});
```

(`emplace_back` and `push_back` are interchangeable in this context.)