# Why does std::{container}::emplace not deduce its argument type?

Tags: c++, std

Suppose I have this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

struct command_node {
    std::string key, value;
};

bool operator==(const command_node &x, const command_node &y) {
    return x.key == y.key;
}

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<command_node> {
        typedef command_node argument_type;
        typedef size_t result_type;
        size_t operator()(const command_node &x) const {
            return std::hash<std::string>()(x.key);
        }
    };
}

using command_set = std::unordered_set<command_node>;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    command_set commands;

    commands.emplace(
        command_node{"system", "running"}
    );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

which just creates an unordered_list of a `command_node` structs. The code is just for illustration.

**Question:** In main, this works (as shown above):

```
    commands.emplace(
        command_node{"system", "running"}
    );
```

but this does not:

```
    commands.emplace(
        {"system", "running"}
    );
```

yet if I replace `emplace` with `insert`, it works either way. In other words,  this works:

```
    commands.insert(
        {"system", "running"}
    );
```

Why does emplace not infer `command_node`?

Comment: Because the `emplace` functions all take arguments by variadic forwarding references, which won't deduce a braced list as anything.

Comment: You should use `commands.emplace("system", "running")`.

Comment: @Jaa-c That only works if the type in the container is not an aggregate (and, of course, has a constructor that takes those argument types)

Comment: @Jaa-c That would work for the code above (which was just for a simple demo), but not for my actual project code, where the second argument ("running") is replaced with a container itself. The second argument is where the initializer_list comes into play.

Comment: Ok, but then there's no advantage of using emplace...

Comment: @Jaa-c Well almost. I can at least save myself from one extra construction of const char * to std::string for the first argument.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207232/emplace-back-not-working-with-stdvectorstdmapint-int

Comment: @NathanOliver Good find. Thanks.

Comment: @BlairFonville you can use `commands.emplace("system", Bar{x,y,z})` in the "real code".  Emplace isn't "recursive". Also , these braced lists aren't `initializer_list` s .

Comment: @M.M Thanks. Yes, that is what I am doing in the project code. Aren’t they, initializer_list’s though? If Bar is a std::vector, or some other container, I thought that’s the overload that {} called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that perfect forwarding based on forwarding references fails with braced initializer lists: to the compiler, this is a "non-deduced context". Instead, pass the arguments as they are passed to the container's underlying value type constructor.

Insert methods differ: they accept either a `const value_type&` lvalue reference or an rvalue reference (`value_type&&`). Hence, passing a braced initializer list that initializes the type works out well.

Comment: That makes sense. Regarding: "Instead, pass the arguments as they are passed to the container's underlying value type constructor" - I can't actually do this in my actual code, since my arguments are themselves constructed with initializer lists. But, I get your point. Thanks.

Comment: @lubgr We all better stick to the agreed upon naming by the committee, and use *Forwarding References* instead of *Universal References*: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist That's a good hint. I adjusted the term.