# Why can an aggreggate struct be brace-initialized, but not emplaced using the same list of arguments as in the brace initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, aggregate, emplace

It seems like [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eaaba108fb9a610e):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct bla
{
    std::string a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<bla> v;
    v.emplace_back("string", 42);
}
```

could be made to work properly in this case, but it doesn't (and I understand why). Giving `bla` a constructor solves this, but removes the aggregateness of the type, which can have far-reaching consequences.

Is this an oversight in the Standard? Or am I missing certain cases where this will blow up in my face, or is it just not as useful as I think?

Comment: Long story short: `emplace_back` (and all of the similar forwarding factory functions, such as `std::make_unique`) always use parentheses to construct the object. Why that is, I don't know.

Comment: @Quentin That's related to perfect forwarding of the arguments. I would think there's be a SFINAE trick to do that if possible, else resort to brace init that also works for aggregates.

Comment: On aggregate structs/classes, creating an intermediate copy of the object, before it is inserted into the vector, is usually not too bad, as most operations can be inlined. So `v.push_back(bla { "string", 42 });` works for C++ standards from C++11 to C++17. From C++20 on, `v.emplace_back("string", 42);` works as expected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is this an oversight in the Standard?

It is considered a defect in the standard, tracked as [LWG #2089](http://wg21.link/LWG2089), which was resolved by C++20. There, constructor syntax can perform aggregate initialization on an aggregate type, so long as the expressions provided wouldn't have called the copy/move/default constructors. Since all forms of indirect initialization (`push_back`, `in_place`, `make_*`, etc) uses constructor syntax explicitly, they can now initialize aggregates.

Pre-C++20, a good solution to it was elusive.

The fundamental problem comes from the fact that you cannot just use braced-init-lists willy-nilly. List initialization of types with constructors can actually *hide* constructors, such that certain constructors can be impossible to call through list initialization. This is the `vector<int> v{1, 2};` problem. That creates a 2-element `vector`, not a 1-element vector whose only element is 2.

Because of this, you cannot use list initialization in generic contexts like `allocator::construct`.

Which brings us to:

> I would think there's be a SFINAE trick to do that if possible, else resort to brace init that also works for aggregates.

That would require using the `is_aggregate` type trait from C++17. But there's a problem with that: you would then have to propagate this SFINAE trick into *all* of the places where indirect initialization is used. This includes `any/variant/optional`'s `in_place` constructors and emplacements, `make_shared/unique` calls, and so forth, none of which use `allocator::construct`.

And that doesn't count user code where such indirect initialization is needed. If users don't do the same initialization that the C++ standard library does, people will be upset.

This is a sticky problem to solve in a way that doesn't bifurcate indirect initialization APIs into groups that allow aggregates and groups that don't. There are [many possible solutions](https://github.com/NicolBolas/Proposal-Ideas/blob/master/Towards%20a%20Fix%20For%20LWG%202089.md), and none of them are ideal.

The language solution is the best of the bunch.

Answer (score 5):

23.2.1/15.5

> T is EmplaceConstructible into X from args, for zero or more arguments
> args, means that the following expression is well-formed:
>
> `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, args)`

23.2.1/15

> [Note: A container calls `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, args)` to construct an element at p using args. The default construct in `std::allocator` will call `::new((void*)p) T(args)`, but specialized allocators may choose a different definition. —end note ]

So, default allocator uses a constuctor, changing this behavior could cause backward compatibility loss. You could read more in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8783004/4759200.

Also there is an issue ["Towards more perfect forwarding"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4462.html) and some random [discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/k5aVvGzig8Y) about it's future.

Comment: I don't see how you end up with "changing this behaviour could cause backward compatibility loss" from reading the linked answer. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @rubenv I took that from original source (http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2089) "Altering `std::allocator<T>::construct` to use list-initialization would, among other things, give preference to `std::initializer_list` constructor overloads, breaking valid code in an unintuitive and unfixable way...".

Comment: that seems like an unqualified statement. It could use list-initialization if and only if the non-list-initialization call is impossible. Hmm this is not the place to discuss that I guess.

Comment: It seems that is what the proposed solution does actually. It's just suboptimal in the grand scheme of things.