# emplace_back() vs push_back when inserting a pair into std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, push, emplace

I defined the following

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > my_vec;
my_vec.push_back( {1,2} ); //this works
my_vec.emplace_back( {1,2} ); // this doesn't work
std::pair<int,int> temp_pair = {1,2}; 
my_vec.emplace_back( temp_pair );         //this works
```

I am compiling with c++11. The third line is problematic, but I thought you can use `emplace_back()` anywhere that you have `push_back()`, but this is apparently wrong. Why does the third line not work?

Comment: Works `my_vec.emplace_back(1,2); `

Comment: Why does the using `({1,2})` not work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) takes a variadic parameter pack as argument:

> ```
> template< class... Args >
> reference emplace_back( Args&&... args );
> ```

When you call it like this: `emplace_back({1, 2})` you are calling it with one argument i.e. `{1, 2}` and the `Args` cannot be deduced. That is because of how the language has evolved. In C++ `{1, 2}` doesn't have a type. It is a brace enclosed init-list and can be used in certain types of initializations, but all require the type of the initialized to be known. That is why `temp_pair = {1,2};` works, because the type of `temp_pair` is know and has a constructor matching `(int, int)`.

Anyway `emplace_back` wasn't supposed to be used like that, but like this instead:

```
my_vec.emplace_back(1, 2);
```

Also please note that even if these work:

```
my_vec.emplace_back(std::pair<int, int>{1, 2});
my_vec.emplace_back(temp_pair);
```

**They shouldn't be used**. They add no advantage over push_back. The whole point of `emplace_back` is to avoid creating a temporary `T`. The above calls all create the temporary `std::pair<int, int>`.

---

> but I thought you can use `emplace_back()` anywhere that you have
>   `push_back()`

For the most part that's correct. At least that was the intention. And you can indeed use it in your cese. You just have to adjust the syntax a little. So instead of `push_back({1, 2})` you can use `emplace_back(1, 2)`.

There is a situation where unfortunately you can't use `emplace_back`: aggregates.

```
struct Agg
{
    int a, b;
};

auto test()
{
    Agg a{1, 2}; // ok, aggregate initialization

    std::vector<Agg> v;
    v.emplace_back(1, 2); // doesn't work :(
}
```

This doesn't work unless you add a constructor for `Agg`. This is considered an open defect in the standard, but unfortunately they can't find a good solution to this. The problem is with how brace init initialization works and if you use it in generic code you can miss some constructors. For all the nitty-gritty details check this great post: [Why can an aggreggate struct be brace-initialized, but not emplaced using the same list of arguments as in the brace initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43407814/2805305)

Answer (score 5):

## 1) `{1, 2}` is not an expression

The syntax

```
{1, 2}
```

is very "strange" compared to other things in C++.

Normally in C++ you have an expression (e.g. `x + 1.2`) and the expression has a deduced type... for example if `x` is an `int` variable the type of the expression will be `double` because of implicit conversion `int`→`double` and how addition works.

Now back to `{1, 2}`: this is "strange" because despite looking like an expression it's not... it's just syntax and its meaning will depend on where it's used.

In a sense typing here will work the opposite of most C++ places: normally in C++ it's "in"→"out" (the type "emerges" from the components) but here is "out"→"in" (the type is "injected" in the components).

The text `{1, 2}` just doesn't mean enough by itself to be compiled (it can mean different things depending on where it is used).

All this boils down to the fact that `{1, 2}` cannot be used **exactly** like an expression, even if the rules are carefully designed to trick you into thinking it does.

## 2) `emplace_back` accepts constructor parameters

`emplace_back` was designed to be able to build the object directly inside the final place in the container... the expected parameters are parameters of a constructor and this is done to avoiding creating a temporary object just to be able make a copy for the final destination and then throwing it away.
The expected parameter of `emplace_back` are therefore `1` and `2`... not a single thing because NOT building a temporary single thing is exactly the reason `emplace_back` was designed for.

You can pass `emplace_back` an instance because the contained type has a copy constructor and the instance is considered a parameter for the copy (move) constructor, not an object to be copied (moved) into destination (what `push_back` expect). The operations performed in this case are the same, but the point of view is different.

## Consequences

To summarize: `emplace_back` cannot use `{1, 2}` because it can accept anything (so doesn't provide enough "context") and that syntax has not enough meaning. `push_back` instead can accept it because it expects a specific type and this provides enough context for interpreting the syntax `{1, 2}`.
This is a simplified explanation but, as usual, C++ went into a direction of even more parsing complexity and special cases, so I can understand why things are not clear for you.

The key point however is that `emplace_back` was not meant to take a full object... for that use `push_back`. The new `emplace_back` construct should be used when you want to pass the CONSTRUCTOR PARAMETERS for building the final object in the container.