# Cannot emplace_back() a braced initializer on a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl, push-back, emplace

This is somewhat related to a previous question I asked regarding using `emplace_back` on a vector of pairs. [emplace_back() vs push_back when inserting a pair into std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900865/emplace-back-vs-push-back-when-inserting-a-pair-into-stdvector)

Now my question pertains to using `emplace_back` on a vector of vectors.

Here is the code that I am questioning about with comments

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;

matrix.emplace_back({1,2,3}); //doesn't compile

matrix.emplace_back(1,2,3); //doesn't compile

matrix.push_back({1,2,3}); //works and does what is expected (insert a vector made of {1,2,3} into matrix);

matrix.emplace_back(std::vector<int>{1,2,3});   //works but 
//defeats the purpose of using emplace_back since this makes a copy
//and is thus equivalent to push_back in this case?

matrix.emplace_back(3,2) //this compiles, 
//but it seems to insert a vector of size 3 made of 2s into the matrix. 
//not actually sure why it does this
```

So, from this, `matrix.emplace_back(std::vector<int>{1,2,3});` seems to be the only correct way to use `std::vector<T>::emplace_back` on a vector of vectors, but this seems to offer no advantages over `push_back`. Is my understanding on this matter correct?

Also, could someone explain why `matrix.emplace_back(3,2)` is inserting a vector of size 3 made of 2s into the matrix?

Comment: `matrix.emplace_back(3,2)` uses the constructor `vector(std::size_t size, const T& value)`.

Comment: @jarod42 Oops, totally missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{1, 2, 3}` cannot be deduced to `initializer_list<int>` in this case (which is what the `vector<int>` constructor you want to use expects.) So you need to help it along a bit:

```
matrix.emplace_back(initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3});
```

This is not required when using `push_back()`. I don't know the exact details, but `emplace_back()` is a function template while `push_back()` is not. Deduction rules for templates are different (way more strict.) And a braced initializer has no type. Because of that, it comes with its own special rules on how type deduction works.

As for efficiently, this:

```
matrix.emplace_back(vector<int>{1, 2, 3});
```

constructs two vectors. An empty vector in `matrix`, and the passed temporary. The temporary is moved into the empty vector. So it's not that bad really.

However, this:

```
matrix.emplace_back(initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3});
```

Only constructs one vector, using the constructor that accepts an initializer_list. Note that there's no "extra" `initializer_list` object being created here. Such an object is going to be created anyway when creating any vector using braced initialization:

```
vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
```

This also creates an `initializer_list` object, because that's what the vector constructor takes.

As for why `emplace_back(2,3)` works, that's because there's a vector constructor that takes a size and a value.

Comment: A couple of follow-ups: 
(1) `push_back` allows {1,2,3} to be deducted to `initializer_list<int>`, it appears. Is there a particular reason why `emplace_back` doesn't also allow for this functionality? 

(2) Is matrix.emplace_back(initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3}) any different from matrix.emplace_back(vector<int>{1, 2, 3}). It seems like doing it this way goes through a vector constructor, and then an initializer_list constructor, whereas in your way it just simply goes through an initializer_list constructor.  So seems your way would be slightly more efficient?

Comment: @Iamanon I don't have the full rules of deduction in my head, but I hope I clarified my answer well enough now.