# too many arguments to function std::make_shared<vector>

Tags: c++, vector, initializer-list, list-initialization, make-shared

I am missing something with `std::make_shared`. Can't it resolve the type of a `std::initializer_list`, or am I doing something else wrong?

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A {};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::vector<A> veca{A(), A{}, a}; // this works ofc
    std::vector<A> vecb({A(), A{}, a}); // this too

    std::make_shared<std::vector<A>>(vecb); // and this, ofc
    std::make_shared<std::vector<A>>({a}); // what's wrong here?
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:21:41: error: too many arguments to function ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::vector; _Args = {}]’
     std::make_shared<std::vector<A>>({a});
                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:82:0,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/shared_ptr.h:632:5: note: declared here
     make_shared(_Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Live example: https://onlinegdb.com/r1DlHquDL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::shared\_ptr and initializer lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820981/stdshared-ptr-and-initializer-lists). But there are no exact reasons why this happens :(

Comment: try "std::make_shared<std::vector<A>>(vector<A>{a});" I think its related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483606/cannot-emplace-back-a-braced-initializer-on-a-vector-of-vectors

Comment: @user3365922 That answer says that it's a compiler issue or perfect forwarding not being perfect. I now I can cast the braces to a std::vector<A> or a initializer list, but I was looking for something more elegant

Comment: Relevant part of the latest C++ Draft: [temp.deduct.call/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#1). I believe this applies: _Otherwise, an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced contexts_, but the error message is kind-of misleading, so I am not 100% sure. With Clang, the substitution fails as expected. Minimal demo: https://godbolt.org/z/HvDPms.

Comment: @DanielLangr looks good to me. The error message is misleading indeed, but clang gives me a "no matching function for call [...]" instead, soo...

Comment: The code of _more-minimal_ demo (can't edit anymore my previous comment): `template <typename... Ts>
void f(Ts&&...); int main() { f({1}); }`.

Comment: The `non-deduced context` is what I was looking for, so if anyone can paste this into an answer, I would be grateful :-) Oh, and that the error message is misleading too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following minimal example of your problem:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void f(Ts&&...);  // replacement for std::make_shared

int main()
{  
  f({1});
}
```

This case is described in the C++ Standard in [[temp.deduct.call/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#1):

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it `P`) that contains template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`) as described below. If removing references and cv-qualifiers from `P` gives
> `std::initializer_list<P′>` or `P′[N]` for some `P′` and `N` and the argument is a non-empty initializer list ([dcl.init.list]), then deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer list independently, taking `P′` as separate function template parameter types `P′i` and the `i`th initializer element as the corresponding argument. In the `P′[N]` case, if `N` is a non-type template parameter, `N` is deduced from the length of the initializer list. **Otherwise, an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context** ([temp.deduct.type]).

In your case, the last sentence applies. Interestingly, the error message says something else with GCC, which is weird. With Clang, the error message is clear:

> `error: no matching function for call to 'f'`
>
> `note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced incomplete pack <(no value)> for template parameter 'Ts'`